# What is the difference between embeddedViewRef and templateRef?

Tags: angular, ng-template

[reference page](https://angular.io/api/core/EmbeddedViewRef)

An embedded view can be referenced from a component other than the hosting component whose template defines it, or it can be defined independently by a TemplateRef.
What is the meaning of the above statement?

I couldn't understand the difference between templateRef and embeddedViewRef

Comment: Please explain with an example?

Comment: Please don't only post a link. Questions should contain all essential code in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateRef is a basically reference to a template - a RULE for piece of html that you don't see yet, but you can build many pieces of html with it.

EmbeddedViewRef is a reference to already rendered piece of html. It could have been built with the help of some Template ref. The reason it is called "embedded" is because it is bound to its parent component change detection and in most cases also to its injector tree

```
<ng-template #myTpl> <!-- here is a template, and myTpl is a template ref.
no html will be rendered in this place at all, 
it is like a function, that has not been called yet 
-->
 <div> some content </div>
</ng-template>

<div *ngTemplateOutlet="myTpl"> 
<!-- here we use myTpl template to create embedded view with 
the help of ngTempalteOutlet directive. 
This directive will have embeddedViewRef in its code and this is the place where we will have some html rendered
-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain with an example. To understand better

Comment: made an update with a pice of code

Comment: Can we create variables for embeddedViewRef like we create templateRef variables.

Comment: sure, you can define variables on a template like this `<ng-template #tpl let-myVal="contextVal">`, and when embedded view is craeted it is possible to pass these vars in context `<div *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl; context: {contextVal: 123}">`

Comment: Okay Can we access embeddedViewRef with @viewchild like we are accessing ng-template with #tpl

Comment: usually you don't need to do it. in my example ngTemplateOutlet directive created the embedded view and it has a ref for sure. if you render embeddedView in a custom code you would also have the reference, but in this my example probably not possible to get it directly, as why would you need it anyway? directive handles it in an easier way for you. You could get the directive with the helpf of ViewChild and get the ref from it, but it could break the directive's logic

Comment: if you want to do something specific try to describe the problem. SO community will try to help you with a best option or direct you to a framework API suitable to solve the problem